# how to check active child router from parent router or parent router against?

Tags: angular, if-statement, conditional-statements, router, angular-routing

How to possible check Children Router Active Or Not, Show The status true or false in angular 4,
 Now currently I'm use :
    /*
    @angular/cli: 1.4.4
    node: 8.6.0
    typescript: 2.3.4
    @angular/router: 4.4.4
*/

my Parent route is:

```
const routes:Routes=[
    {
        path: '', component: SummaryOfFindingsComponent,
        children:[
            {
                path:'data-time-frame', component: DataTimeFrameComponent
            },
            {
                path:'email-address', component: EmailAddressesComponent
            },
            {
                path:'repair-orders', component: RepairOrdersComponent
            },
            {
                path:'total-records', component:TotalRecordsComponent
            },
            {
                path:'unique-households', component: UniqueHouseholdsComponent
            },
            {
                path:'unique-vins', component: UniqueVinsComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Parent component is :

```
export class SummaryOfFindingsComponent implements OnInit {
    isUserSelected;
    constructor() { this.isUserSelected=false; }
    ngOnInit() { }
    isUserItemSelect(){
        this.isUserSelected=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Import your parent component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

and life cycle hooks ngOnInit() And create Refarence Of ActivatedRoute

```
constructor(private activeRouter:ActivatedRoute) {}
```

And Write Some code in your ngOnInit functions here..

```
ngOnInit() {
    var _activeChild = this.activeRouter.children.length;
    if (_activeChild!=0) {
        //your active children 1 or more than children then active 1,otherwise it is 0
    }
}
```

Note: This code is working my app ( Thank You )

Comment: This Work Only First time loading parent component, but I have need to any router change in this page

Comment: Subscriber to activeRouter.params in ngOnInit() if you want to keep track of changes.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to watch for children in an Observable...

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
  filter(event => (event as ActivationEnd).snapshot.component === SearchFeatureComponent),
  map(event => (event as ActivationEnd).snapshot.children.length),
  distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(children => console.warn('route children', children))
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed a simple Observable solution that would emit `false` when no child routes were active.

Went with:

```js
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  readonly childActive$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    switchMap(() => of(this.route.children.length > 0))
  );
```